# How do I update the latest version of Curl on windows 2022 server

Tags: windows, curl

My current version is 7.831, I have downloaded the current version but whenever I check it still brings out the old version. I am unable to delete the old version (if at all possible). How do I update curl?

[old curl version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GcfV.png)

[old and new curl .exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47FES.png)